# Block internet access based on wifi connection

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, firewall, comodo-firewall

I'm planning on buying an ultrabook with Windows 10.

I'll use my Android 7.1.2 phone as hotspot to access internet from my ultrabook when I'm on the fly.

But I can't let my ultrabook's OS and apps acess internet freely, because my phone's plan provide me only 2GB/month. Basicly I'll only use FireFox and IM.

On the other hand, when I'm home I wanna use internet freely thru my WiFi.

The best solution would be ultrabook to block all access except what I explicitly allow when I'm connected to my phone's WiFi, and allow other apps when I'm on home's WiFi.

An alternative would be to block when I'm on WiFi, and allow when I'm on ethernet, and buy an USB ethernet adapter.

Can somebody point me some direction?

Comment: Turn off auto-updates... what else downloads stuff in the background without asking you? Don't run those programs

Comment: Comodo Firewall lists a lot of programs on my PC accessing internet. One huge I can remember is Dropbox.